# HLS over IIS with Smooth Streaming Format SDK

Tags: c++, iis, http-live-streaming, smooth-streaming

I'm trying to run HLS over IIS and Smooth Streaming via Silverlight works fine but not HLS.
What I have:

- New Live Smooth Streaming Publishing Point with HLS support enabled;
- Connected Publishing Point via Smooth Streaming Format SDK and sending H264 samples to IIS in live mode.
- IIS creates *.ismv, *.ism, and empty *.m3u8
- Smooth Streaming over Silverlight  goes fine.

Problem is that there is no *.ts files created and m3u8 file is empty as well, that's why HLS doesnt work. No errors or warnings in Event Viewer.

Note: *.ismv could be transformed to *.ts file with all necessary manifests via Transform Manager IIS extension which means (I suppose) that H264 stream is okay.

Comment: Maybe your expectations are wrong. No ts file or m3u8 file will be created on the filesystem. They're generated in memory and sent as a response to HTTP requests.

Comment: Seems that Dynamic Packaging is available only on Azure Media Services but not IIS SS, that's why I suppose these files are necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some investigation I found what was the problem, to have HLS during live publishing you need to push not only h264 stream but AAC audio as well. Hope It will help somebody.

Comment: Consider that IIS SS will not generate m3u8 if no audio is passed to it event using h264.